# Probability calculation for diabetes prediction

Tags: probability

I have collected diabetes patient details. Each user details contains his symptoms, he might have diabetes in symptoms and might not have.

Currently what I am doing:

If patient A have x and y symptoms. And we find 20 patients who have x and y along with diabetes as a symtoms out of 100 patients. So we count A has 20℅(20/100) probability of having diabetes.

Is this correct way of predicting diabetes possibility for the patient?

I appreciate if someone help me to make it more intuitive or may way to play with probablity value.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, assuming that the 100 patients are *all* the patients from your patient pool that exhibit symptoms x and y, including the 20 who *do* have diabetes.

So, your calculation is a first estimate of the probability that a patient from your pool has diabetes.

Note however, that your pool of patients seems to include only "patients", which are people with symptoms. So your estimate may only be an estimate for "patients". Maybe not for healthy people.

Comment: Thanks. But I think most of user who have some health issue they will only use this system. So we can consider all users as patient only, isnt? There is case where user has x,y,z,a,b symptoms and only x and y symtoms matches. Any other thing can be retrived from this?

Comment: I think so too, but I'd rather know for sure. If you believe all your "users" are similar to the patients in you pool, then you're fine. Otherwise, you'd have to add a large number of people's details to your data and see by how much your probabilities stay the same. Essentially, you'd be interested in the prevalance of x and y in the larger population if you wish to generalise beyond your patient pool.

Comment: thanks for your input. Can you please review - http://ec2-52-41-34-62.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/ it will give you little clear picture

Answer (score 1):

Beside probabilistic approach, you can use parametric (bayes ) or non-parametric classification models such as decision tree, NN or SVM .